# Python how to share an object between methods in a class?

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I am making a game that requires an object to be shared between multiple methods in a class, I am having issues where the methods don't recognise the object even though it has been created. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
import Economy

Class Example:
    economy = Economy.Economy()

    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test
    def exampleMethod1(self):
        economy.getMoney()
    def exampleMethod2(self)
        economy.addMoney(1)
```

Python gives me an error in the methods and says the object doesn't exist.

Comment: That should be `self.economy.getMoney()` or `Example.economy.getMoney()`; that's a *class attribute*, it's not in the global scope. Also `'Class' != 'class'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `self` object to share objects between methods of a class. Your code would become:

```
import Economy

Class Example:
    economy = Economy.Economy()

    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test
    def exampleMethod1(self):
        self.economy.getMoney()
    def exampleMethod2(self)
        self.economy.addMoney(1)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This creates a separate instance of `Economy.Economy` for each instance.

Comment: Don't make it in `__init__` at all. Leave the definition where it was; `self` will access class attributes just fine, as long as you don't reassign them, they remain class attributes. Making a global that you assign as the attribute on every instance is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, its been a while since I've used classes. Thanks for your input, I have updated the answer.